# Make image scale depending on resolution

Tags: html, css, image

I have a `width:100%` image as the header of my website, like [here:http://directdatanou.comli.com/](http://directdatanou.comli.com)

How can I make the image scale depending on screen resolution?

I tried using the image as background of a div, like below:

```
 <div id="header" class="latime_100p">

    </div>
```

with css:

```
#header{
    background: #5b6773 url("../grafica/header.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    height:500px;
}
```

But it doesn't scale right on big resolutions (it shows only parts of the image as the screen width and height grow).

So I ended up with using the image directly?

How can I make it scale gracefully depending on resolution?

Thank you.

Comment: you have set a min-width on the header div, image and other divs which forces the page to be that wide (1280px wide in your case), and it creates a horizontal scroll bar for you page in the browser instead of making the page 100% of the screen size. 
if you want it responsive (fluid across all screen sizes), remove the min-width's on all divs and add width:100%, height: auto to the img styles
OR, set a media query with different breakpoints that loads different styles depending on the resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that ALL image is showing:

```
<img src="...." class="img">

.img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

That's all

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and how it's displaying now